# I am not able to Loop through the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So I am trying to loop through the dataframe and dropping columns based on a condition , but I am getting errors like :
Keyerror: 1
when I use df_X.loc[:,1] , even though there is a column named 1

If I try to use df_X.iloc[:,i] since all the columns are named in numbers I get error Too many indexers

Just so I am clear the columns have name from 0-590, so they are numbers not alphanumeric

Code For when using loc

```
cols = df_X.columns
for i in range(len(cols)):
  if (df_X.loc[:,i].isnull().sum())/len(df_X) > .20:
     df_X.drop(i,axis=1,inplace=True)
  else: df_X= df_X.loc[:,i].replace(np.nan,np.mean(df_X.loc[:,i]))
```

Code when I am using iloc

```
cols = df_X.columns
for i in range(len(cols)):
  if (df_X.iloc[:,i].isnull().sum())/len(df_X) > .20:
     df_X.drop(i,axis=1,inplace=True)
  else: df_X= df_X.iloc[:,i].replace(np.nan,np.mean(df_X.iloc[:,i]))
```

Comment: `df_X.loc[:,"1"]`?

Comment: What is the output of `print(df_X.columns)`?

Comment: Index(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
       ...
       '580', '581', '582', '583', '584', '585', '586', '587', '588', '589'],
      dtype='object', length=590) @Corralien

Comment: how do I loop , i cant add double quotes , for some reason it stops at 1 saying Key error: 1 even though there is a column named 1 @PabloC

Comment: So @PabloC is right. You should use `for i in df_X` and use `df_X.loc[:, i]`

Comment: I have an if statement too , i need to drop when the nan values is more than 20% in a column else replace them with mean @Corralien

Comment: Didnt work , can you paste the whole code block @Corralien Thank you

Comment: Try the code of the answer below. Does it work?

Comment: I need it to be in a for loop, those two operations @Corralien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to drop columns where number of nan is greater than 20% and replace other nan values with the mean of the column:

```
m = df_X.isna().mean().le(0.2)
df_X = df_X.loc[:, m].fillna(df_X.mean())
```

Reproducible example:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)
df_X = pd.DataFrame(rng.uniform(0, 1, (10, 590)))
df_X = df_X * np.random.choice([1, np.nan], (10, 590), p=(0.7, 0.3))
```

Your code fixed:

```
for i in df_X.columns:
    if (df_X[i].isnull().sum() / len(df_X)) > .20:
        df_X.drop(i, axis=1, inplace=True)
    else:
        df_X[i] = df_X[i].replace(np.nan, np.mean(df_X[i]))
```

Comment: If In a column there are more than 20% of NaN values i drop it , if its less than 20% then i use the mean of the column to replace those NaN values @Corralien

Comment: It's exactly what my code does @Pree07 :)

Comment: what is mean().le(0.2). what is the le() here @Corralien

Comment: "less or equal" the opposite of "greater than" because I don't drop the columns but keep them.

Comment: I found your problem: `if (df_X[i].isnull().sum()) / len(df_X) > .20:` (check the second parenthesis after sum. You need to use: `if (df_X[i].isnull().sum() / len(df_X)) > .20:`

Comment: I'm getting Key error '0' even though there is a column named 0 @Corralien
 The thing is the code is not going past this if statement, getting Too many indexers or the '0' I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem that you are having is with using integer instead of a string in df_X.loc[:,1] (df_X.loc[:,'1'] is correct), as Pablo mentioned.
Having said that, consider the following code:

```
# Calculate the percentage of null values in each column
null_percentages = df.isnull().mean() * 100

# Create a list of column names that have null percentages greater than 20%
columns_to_drop = null_percentages[null_percentages > 20].index

# Drop the columns from your DataFrame
df_dropped = df.drop(columns=columns_to_drop)
```

Comment: It has to be in a loop  doing two things drop when NaN percentage in a column is greater than 20% , else replace those NaN values in the column with the mean of the column. @Eriks Markevics

Comment: 'IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)  
<ipython-input-140-e08ed77952a6> in <cell line: 1>()  
      1 for i in df_X:  
----> 2   if (df_final_X.loc[:,i].isnull().sum())/len(df_X) > .20:  
      3      df_final_X.drop([i],axis=1,inplace=True)  
      4   else:  
      5     df_final_X= df_X.loc[:,i].replace(np.nan,np.mean(df_final_X.loc[:,i]))    


IndexingError: Too many indexers'

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem in the last line of the code guys
df_X[i] = df_X[i].replace(np.nan, np.mean(df_X[i]))

This changed the whole dataframe into one column, thats why i got Too many indexers as an error. Thank you for all the help guys, I appreciate it.
@Corralien @Eriks Markevis

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).